# Auth Flow issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to make sure a user exists before giving them access to a certain path.

I have a function that gets the user, and one that requires the auth:

```
function getUser() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/getUser',
    method: 'GET'
  }).done(data => {
    if(data.user == "no user"){
      console.log('permission denied');
      alert('you must be logged in to access this page.')
      return null
    } else {
      console.log('permission granted');
      return true
    }
  });
}

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!getUser()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    });
  }
}
```

I then apply the require function *onEnter*

```
  <Route path="/modules" component={ModulesData} onEnter={requireAuth} />
```

I can see my console logs are correct based on wether or not the user is logged in however, regardless of the user status we are always rerouted back to the login page.

Here is my **index.js** for additional clarity:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute, Redirect } from 'react-router';

import App from './App';

require('./stylesheets/main.scss');



function getUser() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/getUser',
    method: 'GET'
  }).done(data => {
    if(data.user == "no user"){
      console.log('permission denied');
      alert('you must be logged in to access this page.')
      return null
    } else {
      console.log('permission granted');
      return true
    }
  });
}

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!getUser()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    });
  }
}

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>

    <Route path="/" component={App}>

      <Route path="/modules" component={ModulesData} onEnter={requireAuth} />

    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the validation in componentDidMount or componentWillReceiveProps instead of onEnter .
Also, try returning false instead of null when there is no user.

Comment: I was trying to do it like they do in the React Router - Auth Flow example (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js).  I.E.:

<Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />

I need to protect a lot of routes, so having to do it inside the actual component would not be ideal.